# TableBlock how to specify table CSS classes

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I am struggling to add CSS classes to Wagtail `StreamField` & `TableBlock` (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8.1/reference/contrib/table_block.html).

Is the way to go to define a filter and use something like:

`{{ child|className:"table table-bordered" }}`

where `className` is my custom filter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, this isn't currently possible with the standard rendering of a TableBlock - the [template used internally to render the block](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/0dc9e5f4a47aaae68dbf18cbaca548b7e5f9fbc0/wagtail/contrib/table_block/templates/table_block/blocks/table.html) has hard-coded `<table>` / `<tr>` / `<td>` tags with no class attributes. However, you could specify a custom template in your `TableBlock` declaration, which would give you full control over the HTML:

```
StreamField([
    # ...
    ('table', TableBlock(template='/path/to/custom/template.html')),
    # ...
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @gasman, thanks for help! A little addition - its better to overwrite this template https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/2af880025a65947955978ff494f8d1cae21ca7c3/wagtail/contrib/table_block/templates/table_block/blocks/table.html because the one you've linked doesnt respect caption

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a good idea. Last time I needed to do something similar I found [this  blogpost](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/adding-css-classes-formfields-in-django-templates/) which gives you a practically copy-and-paste solution to your problem. Django templatetags might have changed since then, but not by much.

EDIT: From the comments, [this seems to be more modular](https://gist.github.com/TimFletcher/034e799c19eb763fa859).